# Reportviewer Missing Datasource

Tags: vb.net, datasource, reportviewer

I created a dataset which contains a table from my SQL Database named "BillHeaders"

Here's what my report viewer looks like, it will contain two reports. One that holds a job number and description, the other that holds a job number, description and contract number.
[image: Reportviewer]

Here are my buttons that will execute either report

[image: Two types of reports]

Here are my reports in my "Reports" folder. Both constructed and ready to go.
[image: Reports folder]

Unfortuantely when I use this code (respectively for each button):

```
Private Sub btnJobNoDesc_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnJobNoDesc.Click
    'Reset the viewer
    frmReportViewer.ReportViewer1.Reset()

    'Dim the required datasources. Need a seperate ReportDatasource for each table in the report
    Dim ReportDataSource1 As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource

    'Give datasource name and set the specific datatables
    ReportDataSource1.Name = "dsBillHeaders_BillHeaders"
    ReportDataSource1.Value = frmReportViewer.dsBillHeaders.BillHeaders

    'Clear the datasources in the report and add the new ones
    frmReportViewer.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    frmReportViewer.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource1)

    frmReportViewer.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer_Tutorial.rptJobNoDesc.rdlc"
    frmReportViewer.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    frmReportViewer.Show()
End Sub
```

I get this result:
[image: Result]

What am I doing wrong with my datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I figured out:

```
Private Sub btnJobNoDesc_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnJobNoDesc.Click
    'Reset the form
    Dim rv As New frmReportViewer

    'Reset the viewer
    rv.ReportViewer1.Reset()

    Dim ds As New dsBillHeaders
    Dim ta As New dsBillHeadersTableAdapters.BillHeadersTableAdapter
    ta.Fill(ds.BillHeaders)

    rv.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer_Tutorial.rptJobNoDesc.rdlc"
    rv.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim sReportDataSource As ReportDataSource
    sReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource()
    sReportDataSource.Name = "dsBillHeaders"
    sReportDataSource.Value = ds.BillHeaders
    rv.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource)

    rv.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    rv.Show()
End Sub
```

Using this code, I can generate multiple forms just by changing the name of the report on the ReportEmbeddedResource, sReportDataSource.Value and the dataset if necessary.

Comment: IS "dsBillHeaders" the dataset name? or the table name.

Comment: dsBillHeaders is the Tablix's dataset name :)

Answer (score 2):

For one you are not setting the processing mode to local

Here is code that works, when I create the report I make sure to have the datasource name in the report correspond to the table name of my dataset, not sure if that is required but it keeps things simpler.

```
       _reportViewerNewContracts.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
        _reportViewerNewContracts.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\NewContractsReport.rdlc"

        Dim reportDataSource1 As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource()
        reportDataSource1.Name = _contractDataset.NewContracts.TableName
        'Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
        reportDataSource1.Value = _contractDataset.NewContracts

        Me._reportViewerNewContracts.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1)
        'fill data 
        _reportViewerNewContracts.RefreshReport()
```

(I have seen lots of sites that recommend the datasetname underscore tablename but that never worked for me)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I just figured another way of doing it. I'll post it as an answer as well